# How much time does it take for firebase analytics first report?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

We wanted to try out the new analytics capabilities provided by firebase and followed all the steps in the getting started guide.

We've run the app, `logged` a lot of events, and it's been a few hours, yet there is no data on the dashboard - We just see a banner saying "Your analytics data will appear here soon"

How much time does it take to get our first reports, events, etc.?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It takes a few hours. I would say it takes like 4 hours or something like that, based on current experiments.

**Firebase** says that it can take up to 24h hours, but the docs say that the dashboard updates "a few times every day".

And if you send the Firebase events to **BigQuery**, they create a new dataset there everyday, but it seems that the "old" events are not sent immediately, maybe that takes a few hours too, don't know yet.

---

If you want to test other features, or see if Firebase is working for your app, you can force a crash, and see it in the Crash panel, cause this works almost real time.
Or you can send a notification to all users, this should work too, and it is faster than waiting for 4h or more to see if it is working really.
Remember to add the dependencies if you are going to try this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

Comment: There's also a thing named DebugView now. By enabling a property through adb, you can view the events in near realtime (it usually takes a coupe seconds to appear here).

Answer (score 33):

From the moment an event is logged it might take up to an hour for the event to be uploaded to Firebase Analytics server. First open is normally uploaded within 15 seconds after the app starts but the exact time depends on many factors. You can enable debug logging to verify the events are logged and uploaded.

On Android:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

On iOS:

1. In Xcode, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme...
2. Select Run from the left menu.
3. Select the Arguments tab.
4. In the Arguments Passed On Launch section, add -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled.

Once the data is uploaded it takes about 3 hours for it to appear in the dashboard.

The export to BugQuery runs once a day so you need 24 hours to see the data after the events were uploaded.

Comment: thumbs up for writing additional details that helps with issue during developing ;)

Answer (score 28):

Why it just so happens I wrote a [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html) on exactly this topic!

You should check it out for all the details, but the tl;dr is "a few hours", unless you're exporting your data to BigQuery.

Comment: Great post. I think you are a bit modest to not mention it's written for the official Firebase Blog to answer this specific question. When I saw that, I knew it was exactly the information I was searching for. I gotta say - with Firebase API, it is the first time I have seen a group of in-house developers (and advocates :) ) for a Google API be so supportive on StackOverflow. About 50% of the time the Firebase questions I seek out on SO have been properly/effectively answered by someone from Firebase.. that's very cool. Just wanted to say sincere thanks to Firebase team for all the nice work

Answer (score 5):

An Android device sends Firebase Analytics data every X hours but you can use the following ADB command to immediately upload analytics data when registering an event:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app your.package.name
```

To check if data is being sent, you can check the logs:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Once uploaded, the data is processed on Firebase servers, and this can take up to 24 hours until you can see the data in the Firebase console.

Comment: Simple and quick fix. Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Firebase Analytics Event Update time on Firebase Console.**

When an event is logged, It might take up to an hour for the event to be uploaded to Firebase Analytics server and to reflect on Firebase console.

You can enable debug logging to verify the events are logged and uploaded using the Android studio's terminal

**- Make sure you are not connected to more than one device/emulator**

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for debugging you can use this Firebase guide to see the logs almost right away:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#ios

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you disable any ad blockers you're using with your browser or whitelist the Firebase console website. If you don't do this, you'll see blank dashboards.