# Firebase analytics with spark package

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I would like to implement firebase to an application I have on the play store. I only want to use it just for the analytics and the notifications function. I'm aware what with the free package you are given 100 simultaneous users who can access your database.

Considering that would I be able to just implement firebase to my app, use it for notification, analytics, and integrate it with admobs all free at change?

I'm aware the real time database is something on its on but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

The [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) clearly lists the products that are paid. The other products are free to use. That indeed includes Firebase Cloud Messaging, Firebase Notifications, Firebase Analytics and AdMob.

Comment: Hi, I am using Firebase analytics for my app since last month. But i experience a reporting delay of 1 day. i am using "SPARK" plan. Is there any way to see live sessions in Firebase just like in Google analytics?

Comment: The data shown in the Firebase Analytics dashboard is typically delayed by 4-5 hours. There is no live analytics view. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report

Comment: ohh so it can't replace Google Analytics :(  Thank you Frank for the quick reply.