# Firebase Analytics not gathering any data from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I followed all the steps mentioned in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/), but when I looked into my [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project), I don't see any of the events that I created.

- Is Firebase Analytics displaying data in real-time?
- Or is Firebase Analytics ignoring emulators?
- Is there a way to check whether my Android app and Firebase are actually connected?

Please help me, I am a new in Firebase Analytics.

Comment: I can only see: session start with value 1, even though I run  the app with several device.

Comment: It takes anywhere between 4 and 24 hours before the analytics panel in the Firebase Console shows data.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report

Answer (score 2):

What you see on the console is not real time data, it has some delay. Quoting from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events):

> You can view aggregrated statistics about your events in the Firebase console dashboards. These dashboards update periodically throughout the day.

If you want to test it immediately, you can apply some logcat options in described in the same document.

Besides that, there's a *minimum session duration* set for 10 seconds. If you open up the app and exit within that given time period, no events will be logged. You can change that value by calling [`setMinimumSessionDuration(long milliseconds)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setMinimumSessionDuration(long)) with an appropriate value.

Comment: Is it normal that after 2 hours, I cannot see any event at all?

Comment: `10-11 16:16:36.220 27152-27246/com.example.tolotranet.livecampus D/FA: Logging event (FE): share_image, Bundle[{_o=app, image_name=UWallet , full_text=locked menu}]` this is a snippet of my logcat.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. To make sure everything is working, I recommend checking back 0.5-1 day or at least like 6 hours later. Your logcat message seems to be fine if you don't see any errors related to Firebase.