# Firebase analytics page is blank but Crash reports are working

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, crash-reports

I am having some trouble integrating my project with Google Firebase analytics. I have followed all the instructions and the integration seems to be complete as I do get Crash reports correctly but the Analytics page is empty.

My build.gradle contents:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
```

The logs seem to suggest its sending the reports.

```
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10298
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app 
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
D/FA: Connected to remote service
D/FA: Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=Demo mode entered, _o=app, _sc=SeatsActivity, _si=-6324821531545085450, content_type=image, item_id=Demo}]
D/FA: Connected to remote service
D/FA: Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=Demo mode exited, _o=app, _sc=SeatsActivity, _si=-6324821531545085450, content_type=image, item_id=Demo}]
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=14578, _sc=SeatsActivity, _si=-6324821531545085450}]
D/FA: Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=User Authenticated, _o=app, content_type=image, item_id=Authentication}]
D/FA: Connected to remote service
D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=11345, _sc=AuthenticationActivity, _si=-6324821531545085449}]
D/FA: Connected to remote service
```

The image seems to suggest there is some analytics but when I go to the Analytics tab its blank. I have waited for couple of days after sending the reports but still the page is blank. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: it can take up to 24h hours for more details check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37348235/3182144

Comment: Its been couple of days already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been using my Office Gmail ID (Enterprise account) and it seems not to support Firebase or this feature might have been blocked by the Admin. I have deleted this project and created the project under my personal GMail ID and everything is working fine.

It would be good to show a warning/information message why the Analytics will not work with an Enterprise account as this wasted couple of days of effort. Also make sure that you are logged onto only one Google account to view Firebase.

Comment: How frustrating-I'm having the same problem, but have already set up AdMob and Google API usage using my Google Apps based login, so don't really want to change all that to link to a different Google Id (and have to push out app updates). Sounds like there is a bug in Firebase Analytics.

Comment: John, you can transfer the ownership to another account. First add the other account as the Owner and delete the current user.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I managed to find another workaround that was simple for me since I am the admin (see my separate response).

Answer (score 1):

I found out that for G Suite / Google Apps / Enterprise accounts Google Analytics is disabled by default.

If you can get in contact with your administrator (or that's you), they can follow the instructions to enable it here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304816

I did this myself, and despite the warning it might take 24 hours, Firebase Analytics page starting working for me straight away.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I was having similar issues and it turned out my adblocker was blocking some stuff. I could see the realtime page but the dashboard and events page were staying blank. Maybe other people have the same issue and are happy to read this.