# Can't see Admob events in Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

I have followed this tutorial: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163 and tried to integrate Admob and Firebase Analytics but I can't see any events (ad_click, ad_impression) in Debug View (as described in verify section).

I have tried with both 11.0.1 version and 10.2.3 (beta) with no success (for Firebase Analytics SDK and Mobile Ads SDK dependencies).

I have also added exception (keep) to Proguard file for FirebaseAnalytics and AppMeasurement.

Admob is correctly linked with Firebase - I know that because I already can see some data from Admob in Firebase Analytics in production where I use version 10.2.6.

Is there a reason why this still wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Firebase support regarding missing Admob events in Firebase Analytics:
"I just heard back from our engineers. They've confirmed that you've configured things correctly, but we're still in the midst of rolling out this functionality, which is why you're only seeing a portion of the traffic. In the near term though, we expect the metrics to converge. "

When I specifically asked about why I don't see events at least in DebugView:
"Same cause - not all devices have this functionality enabled at this time and thus ad_click/ad_impression events are not logged."

Answer (score -1):

Might be that Firebase doesn't refresh their analytics data right away, as, with Google Analytics, it might take a couple of hours, even a day to fully send the reports to the dashboard as mentioned in these posts:

- [How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)
- [How much time does it take for firebase analytics first report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report)

---

> To understand latency with Firebase Analytics, there are two potential
> delays you need to be aware of:
>
> - The time it takes for analytics data on the client to be sent over to
>   the Firebase Analytics servers.
> - The time it takes for Firebase Analytics data to be displayed to you in the Firebase console once
>   it's been received on the server.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I don't think this is the case.

First, in the article that I mention (https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7378163) they explicitely state that we should test in DebugView that should work "real-time".

Second, to use DebugView "you can enable Debug mode on your development device to upload events with a minimal delay" (see more https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview). That I also do and it works just fine with other events.