# Firebase Analytics event are not getting displayed in Events section but in Debug View they are, why?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am adding firebase events by using:

```
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SEARCH_TERM,"searched term")
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH, bundle)
```

The above event is getting displayed in the DebugView mode but not in the events section of the console. Its been like 2 hours i have generated this event.

Please help.

Comment: are you able to see other events in the console? Try enabling de logs and see if there is any problem https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log

Comment: @NilOleart yes i can see the events in DebugView mode.

Comment: I am talking about Android Studio console

Comment: yes I am getting success message there too like:  Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0

Comment: @NilOleart any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its been like 2 hours i have generated this event.

If the events show up in debug view, you have the code wired up correctly. In that case, you'll simply have to wait for the data to show up in the charts, which may take up to 24 hours.

See:

- the Firebase blog post ["How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)
- [How much time does it take for firebase analytics first report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report)